# Adding a custom submit to newform.aspx in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-form

I am currently trying to modify the newform.aspx for a list in SP 2010.  The requirement is to direct a user back to the root site(default.aspx) after submitting the form.  I realize I would need to use Designer for this but not sure about the code that would get this done.  Any assistance appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9792/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to do this is where ever you provide a link to fill out the newform, you change the hyperlink to include ?Source=http://linkyouroyurroot.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  For some reason the simplier option of just modifying the link didn't seem to work.  The button I created is on the home portal site that direscts to newform.aspx with the source query in the url.  Anyway, the SPD option worked well.

Comment: External site link dead.